# Multiple modals with Sweet Alert 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, sweetalert

I have a Sweet Alert 2 modal which includes a form and a button that's supposed to trigger a different form in a different Sweet Alert 2 modal over the exsisting one. Once the user is done with the new form and closes the new modal, the old modal should be exactly as how it was left.

When I try to trigger a new modal on button click, it overwrites the current modal and on quit all modals are closed. I also thought of achieving this with chaining modals example as well. There is the "Next Step" but I could not find a way to add "Previous step" option.

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to the documentation, you can't. Use another library who allows it like [Noty](https://ned.im/noty/#/animations)